# Scopes Does Not Exist on type MsalGuardAuthRequest

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have been using Msal for logging in on my application, but recently my Angular app is no longer building with the current configuration.

I am using a `renewTokenSilent()` function where the `msalService` is being used to check if the page should be refreshed.

```
renewTokenSilent(): Observable<AuthenticationResult> {
  const account = this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0];
  const silentRequest: SilentRequest = {
    account,
    scopes: this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest.scopes,
  };
  // console.log('getTokenSilent called', account, silentRequest);
  return this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(silentRequest).pipe(
    tap((response) => {
      // console.log('Token', response);
      if (!response.accessToken) {
        this.msalService.acquireTokenRedirect(silentRequest);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

However, the `scopes` is no longer working, and I am getting the error: `Property 'scopes' does not exist on type '(authService: MsalService, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => MsalGuardAuthRequest'.`

Everything seemed to be working fine before, but this scopes is no longer working.

I have tried deleting and reinstalling `npm` as well as attempting to upgrade the msal package.

Here is some more code:

```
import { MsalService, MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG, MsalGuardConfiguration } from '@azure/msal-angular';
...
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
...

constructor(
  @Inject(MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG) private msalGuardConfig: MsalGuardConfiguration,
  private msalService: MsalService,
  ...
) {}
```

It appears to be an issue with type checking in Angular. If I make the `msalGuardConfig` `any` then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The `authRequest` property on `MsalGuardConfiguration` can be either an object, or a function that returns an object: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/21123e62ed0c9e99bfe6ed248f2f789a3ee6239a/lib/msal-angular/src/msal.guard.config.ts#L14

You can mitigate the error you are seeing by casting `this.msalService.authRequest` to `MsalGuardAuthRequest`.